# PySide6 QTreeWidget Checkbox SingleSelection

Tags: checkbox, pyqt, pyside, qtreewidget

have a PySide6 QTreeWidget with some Elements and Checkboxes, very simple. What i cannot getting to work is how can i make s Single Selection with the Checkboxes? What works is SingleSelection without the Checkboxes, but not when i only use the Checkboxes itself. I wann use only Checkboxes and not Mouseclicks on the row, i did that with

```
tv.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
tv.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
```

My Idea was set a itemChanged handler function for it and when a checkbox is clicked i run through all items, set all item checkboxes to uncheck with

```
child.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
```

and after that set the item that is selected from the handler to checked.

```
def handle_statechange(item):
    selected_item = item.text(0)
    for i in range(tv.invisibleRootItem().childCount()):
        child = tv.invisibleRootItem().child(i)
        child.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
    item.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Checked)
```

But that doesnt work. How can i make this behavior? Thanks!

Here is small sample Code

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
testdict = {'TEST1': 'Testname1',
            'TEST2': 'Testname2',
            'TEST3': 'Testname3',
            'TEST4': 'Testname4',
            }

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
widget.setWindowTitle("test")
widget.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(widget)
widget.grid.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
widget.hide()

tv = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
tv.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
tv.setIndentation(0)
tv.setColumnCount(4)
tv.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
tv.hideColumn(2)
tv.hideColumn(3)
tv.setHeaderLabels(['NORM', 'NAME'])
tv.header().setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)

strlen_list = []
for k, v in testdict.items():
    strlen_list.append(len(v))
    TreeNodeItem = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem
    treeNode = TreeNodeItem(tv, k)
    treeNode.setText( 0, k )
    treeNode.setText( 1, v )
    treeNode.setText( 2, '512' )
    treeNode.setText( 3, '513' )
    treeNode.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

widget.grid.addWidget(tv, 0, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
label.setText("Testlabel")
widget.grid.addWidget(label, 1, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Testbutton', widget)
button.clicked.connect(test)
widget.grid.addWidget(button, 2, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)

widget.show()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. The check state of items has absolutely **nothing** to do with the selection. Please try to better explain what is your problem and what is the expected result.

Comment: I added small sample Code. My problem is that i wanna set only ONE active checkbox. When i set checkbox from TEST1 to checked and i set checkbox from TEST2 to checked then everything else should be unchecked except TEST2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check state change of items has absolutely nothing to do with the selection and is not directly correlated to mouse clicks, since the user could click on an item but *not* on its checkbox, or could press the space-bar to toggle the check state of the current item.

Assuming that you toggle the check state of items ***ONLY*** using mouse/keyboard and you will *always* have only one checked item at most, you can connect to the [itemChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtreewidget.html#itemChanged) signal and verify if any of its columns has a checked state.

Then you have to store the checked item and column so that you can later verify if any other item has changed and it's different from the previously set checked item.

```py
class ToggleTree(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.lastToggled = None
        self.itemChanged.connect(self.checkToggled)

    def checkToggled(self, item):
        for column in range(item.columnCount()):
            if item.checkState(column):
                break
        else:
            if self.lastToggled and self.lastToggled[0] == item:
                self.lastToggled = None
            return
        if self.lastToggled:
            oldItem, oldColumn = self.lastToggled
            if oldItem != item:
                # prevent recursion
                self.itemChanged.disconnect(self.checkToggled)
                oldItem.setCheckState(oldColumn, 0)
                self.itemChanged.connect(self.checkToggled)
        self.lastToggled = item, column

# ...
tv = ToggleTree()
```

Note: if you only need a 2-dimensional model like in your example, don't use QTreeWidget, but QTableWidget.

Comment: I changed some things to TableWidget and tryed adapt the checkToggled function, but cannot getting to work. Can you help me with that and adapt it to a TableWidget? And is the indentation correct on your code? The for loop and the else?

Comment: @user1701820 without knowing what you did, it's impossible to help you. Before adapting the code to something you don't know yet, I suggest you to familiarize yourself with QTableWidget in order to better understand how it works.